# sending an email in VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, date

I'm pretty basic with VBA & I found the below code for sending an email when a cell value has been exceeded. I am trying to alter the code so the email is sent when either a date is entered into a blank cell (so as to complete an action) or when a cells text goes from "**Ongoing**" to "**Complete**" following the population of a cell with a date. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Not Application.Intersect(Range("J1:J3000"), Target) Is Nothing Then
            If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value > 1 Then
                Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So the text `Complete` will be column **`K`**?

Answer (score 0):

This is to give you a perspective how things work:

Suppose that date is in cell B2 and status is in cell C2.

Enter `=IFERROR(IF(DAY(B2)<>0,"Completed","Ongoing"),"Invalid Date")` to Cell C2  as shown below:

[image]

Enter a date (or anything) to Cell B2 and see how the status changes:

[image]

[image]

Now, insert the following code in your sheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("B2"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If Range("C2").Value = "Completed" Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

When you enter a date to Cell B2 and have the value changed to "Completed" in Cell C2, it will call your sub.

**EDIT:**

If you would like to do this for a range of cell you can use the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("B2:B200"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Completed" Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```